# How to make security on wpf software?

Tags: wpf, security

How do I have a research implement on wpf software?

Comment: Can you precise your question little bit more?

Comment: This question doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) is a GUI framework and doesn't really have much to do with security.

If on the other hand you mean *WCF* (Windows Communication Foundation), which seems possible, then you could start [here](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/33342).

If you're being asked to implement WCF security for a WPF application, then you will need to search for them both. There's lots of help on StackOverflow already as well as pages on Google. Hopefully this answer helps you.

If this doesn't answer your question then you might need to rephrase it.